# Can't create Microsoft Graph API subscription

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-notifications

I want to have some logic executing after user creation event is pushed, so i decided to go into event grid and create subscription for Microsoft Graph API

```
Connect-MgGraph 

Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.ChangeNotifications
    
$params = @{
           changeType = "updated,deleted,created"
           notificationUrl = "EventGrid:?azuresubscriptionid=MyID&resourcegroup=Test&partnertopic=Test&location=eastus"
           lifecycleNotificationUrl = "EventGrid:?azuresubscriptionid=MyID&resourcegroup=Test&partnertopic=Test&location=eastus"
           resource = "users"
           expirationDateTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(4000)
        }
    
New-MgSubscription -BodyParameter $params
```

And I'm getting this error, i don't know how to fix it and didn't find any solution to fix it

```
New-MgSubscription_Create: Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Unauthorized; Reason: ]

Status: 401 (Unauthorized)
ErrorCode: ExtensionError
Date: 2024-02-26T11:01:41

Headers:
Cache-Control                 : no-cache
Transfer-Encoding             : chunked
Vary                          : Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security     : max-age=31536000
request-id                    : c9bb98e5-6c35-43a7-abbe-665e9724ead1
client-request-id             : a3ba1c36-7716-456f-b36d-c54bda198962
x-ms-ags-diagnostic           : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"E","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"003","RoleInstance":"AM1PEPF0003006E"}}
Date                          : Mon, 26 Feb 2024 11:01:41 GM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created one Partner configuration for <kbd>**Sri**</kbd> resource group by authorizing **Microsoft Graph API** to create resources:

[image]

Initially, I too got **same error** when I ran your script to create subscription with user not having <kbd>**User.Read.All**</kbd> permission under tenant:

```
Connect-MgGraph 

Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.ChangeNotifications
    
$params = @{
           changeType = "updated,deleted,created"
           notificationUrl = "EventGrid:?azuresubscriptionid=MyID&resourcegroup=Sri&partnertopic=Demo&location=eastus"
           lifecycleNotificationUrl = "EventGrid:?azuresubscriptionid=MyID&resourcegroup=Sri&partnertopic=Demo&location=eastus"
           resource = "users"
           expirationDateTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(4000)
        }
    
New-MgSubscription -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, make sure to grant <kbd>**User.Read.All**</kbd> permission to signed-in user that differs based on **resource** value or login with user having **Admin** role under tenant.

Now, I ran below PowerShell script by including **`-Scopes`** parameter and got the **response** successfully like this:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All"

Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.ChangeNotifications
    
$params = @{
           changeType = "updated,deleted,created"
           notificationUrl = "EventGrid:?azuresubscriptionid=MyID&resourcegroup=Sri&partnertopic=Test01&location=eastus"
           lifecycleNotificationUrl = "EventGrid:?azuresubscriptionid=MyID&resourcegroup=Sri&partnertopic=Test01&location=eastus"
           resource = "users"
           expirationDateTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(4000)
        }
    
New-MgSubscription -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can also retrieve the created **subscription** details by running below command:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.ChangeNotifications

Get-MgSubscription -SubscriptionId <aboveIDvalue> | fl
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, Event Grid Partner Topic named <kbd>**Test01**</kbd> created successfully as below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Create subscription - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)